# Proving $J(x) < x$ in Riemann's Explicit Formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

There is a function in Riemann's 1859 paper (I will use $J(x)$ as in Edward's book), defined as
\begin{equation*}
J(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \sum_{p^n < x} \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{p^n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \right]\quad\quad x > 0.
\end{equation*}
So, for any given $x > 0$, $J(x)$ is a sum over all whole numbers $\leq x$.  For each such number, that  term in the sum is $1$ for every prime, $1/2$ for every prime square, $1/3$ for every prime cube, etc., and $0$ if that number is a factor of two or more different primes.  (For our purposes, it is not important that the step is only half the stated value if $x$ exactly equals a number factored by only one prime).

It is clear that $J(x) < x$ because no term is greater than $1$ and some terms are less than $1$.  But there is another definition of $J(x)$ in Riemann's paper
\begin{equation}
J(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \pi\left(x^{1/n}\right) = \pi(x) + \frac{1}{2} \pi(x^{1/2}) + \frac{1}{3} \pi(x^{1/3}) + ...,
\end{equation}
where $\pi(x)$ has its usual definition as the prime counting function.

I have attempted (unsuccessfully) to prove that $J(x) < x$ using the second definition of $J(x)$. I will show what I have done so far.

We can assume that $x \geq 2$ because $\pi(x)=0$ (and therefore $J(x) = 0$) for $x < 2$.  Fix $x$.  Then there is a $K \geq 1$ such that $x = 2^K$, and there is a whole number $N$ such that $N \leq K < (N+1)$.  Note that for whole number $n > N$ we have $x^{1/n} < 2$ and therefore $\pi(x^{1/n}) = 0$.  Thus, for our fixed $x$ (and for our associated $N$ and $K$) we have
\begin{equation*}
J(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} \pi\left(x^{1/n}\right) .
\end{equation*}
Now assume that $x > 8$.  (With $x \leq 8$ there are at most three non-zero terms in $J(x)$ and 
$J(x) < x$ is quickly verified by hand).  For $x > 8$, it is easily seen that $\pi(x) < x/2$ since: (1) there are no primes in the 50% of remaining numbers that are factors of two, and (2) there are no primes in the 16.67% of remaining numbers that are odd factors of three.

Replacing $\pi(x)$ with $x/2$, we have
\begin{equation*}
J(x) \leq \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{x^{1/n}}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{x^{1/n}}{2n} 
= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{x^{1/n}}{n}.
\end{equation*}
**The Inequalities**. So we would like to show that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{x^{1/n}}{n} < x\quad\text{(or equally)}\quad \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2^{K/n}}{n} < 2^K.
\end{equation}
I have satisfied myself, empirically, that the inequalities hold (i.e., even after our rough estimate for $\pi(x)$).  But if there is an arithmetico-geometric-like closed form expression (equality or useful inequality), or other way to proceed, I have been unable to find it.

I'll just note one other way to state the inequalities
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{x^{1/n}}{n} 
= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{ x \cdot x^{-(n-1)/n} }{n}  
= x \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n x^{(n-1)/n}},
\end{equation*}
so an equivalent inequality (using $x$ or $2^K$) is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n x^{(n-1)/n}} < 1.
\end{equation}

**My question**: How do you prove the above inequalities? If that is not possible, are there other ways to use the second definition of $J(x)$ to show $J(x) < x$ (of course, not including proof that the second definition of $J(x)$ equals the first)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$N \le \log_{2}x$ so for $x>8, \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{x^{1/n}}{n} \le \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}\log_{2}x <x$ Done!

(as $\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{2\ln 2}\ln x$ has positive derivative when $(\ln 2) (\sqrt{x}) >1$ and that happens already for $x>4$)